# Can Inno Setup install set up a Windows security group?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, windows-security

How can set up a Windows security group as part of a Inno Setup install?

I can't seem to think of the right text to google to figure it out. Perhaps a hint at what to search for would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have found something. I can use "net localgroup" (a Windows command:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490706.aspx). That is my hint. My search hint....

So now I need to learn how to ask a user for input (CreateInputQueryPage), and execute the command... but that would be a different question if I get stuck on those steps... here is that question:[How do you execute command line tools without utilizing command prompt in an inno setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051357/how-do-you-execute-command-line-tools-without-utilizing-command-prompt-in-an-inn/28051810#28051810)

Comment: No. Please do not create and run a batch file. Inno Setup can execute command line tools for you without utilizing command prompt.

Comment: @TLama So that leads me to a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051357/how-do-you-execute-command-line-tools-without-utilizing-command-prompt-in-an-inn (How do you execute command line tools without utilizing command prompt in an inno setup?)