# How do you execute command line tools without using batch file in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I now understand that "Inno Setup can execute command line tools for you without utilizing batch file." ([Can Inno Setup install set up a Windows security group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992605/can-inno-setup-install-setup-a-windows-security-group)) It makes sense that it would be able to do that. From my web searches into Inno Setup thus far, I can not find an starting place to understand how to do this. A complete answer may not be necessary, if I just had some further hint as to what to look for, that would probably be good enough.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It was meant that you don't need to create and execute a batch script (with a single command), nor execute the tool through the command prompt (like shown below):

```pascal
Exec('cmd.exe', '/c "net localgroup ..."', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Result);
```

But you directly execute the tool instead:

```pascal
Exec('net.exe', 'localgroup ...', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Result);
```

The same applies to the `[Run]` section:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c ""net localgroup ..."""
```

Better would be this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "net.exe"; Parameters: "localgroup ..."
```

Comment: A link to the Exec help page: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec

Comment: I would like to emphasize that the /c switch is needed for s cmd.exe command, for example:
[Run] 
Filename: "cmd.exe"; Parameters: "/c echo {app} & pause";

Comment: How do I execute a command that use double quotes, example: cd “c:\ my folder with spaces”